# how does equating lists work? -basic concepts of mutable

Tags: python, python-3.x

why in the following case list2 is not `[3,5]` ?

```
>>>list1=[3,5]
>>>list2=list1
>>>list1[0]=2
>>>list1
   [2,5]
>>>list2
   [2,5]
```

but when I try here it is[3,5]:

```
>>>list1=[3,5]
>>>list2=list1
>>>list1=[3,5,7]
>>>list2
   [3,5]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python variable names point at objects.

```
list2=list1
```

causes `list2` to point at the same object as `list1`.

```
list1[0]=2
```

modifies the `list1` object in-place, so `list2` is affected as well.

[image]

In contrast,

```
list1=[3,5,7]
```

causes `list1` to point at a different list. So `list2` and `list1` no longer point at the same object. Thus `list2` remains equal to `[3, 5]` in the second situation.
[image]

See [Mark Ransom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140747/190597) for a nice explanation of Python's variable / object / assignment model.

The pictures above were generated by the [Online Python Tutor visualizer](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=list1%3D%5B3,5%5D%0Alist2%3Dlist1%0Alist1%5B0%5D%3D2%0Alist1%0A%23+%5B2,5%5D%0Alist2%0A%23+%5B2,5%5D%0A%0Alist1%3D%5B3,5%5D%0Alist2%3Dlist1%0Alist1%3D%5B3,5,7%5D%0Alist2%0A%23+%5B3,5%5D%0A&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=9). You can use it to see how the assignments change the variable's values step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you change the object being pointed to by `list1` and `list2` "in place". In the second, you assign `list1` to a *completely new object*, leaving only `list2` pointing to the original object. Use `id()` or `is` to see when two names point to the same object:

```
>>> list1=[3,5]
>>> list2=list1
>>> list1[0]=2
>>> list1 is list2
True
```

versus

```
>>> list1=[3,5]
>>> list2=list1
>>> list1=[3,5,7]
>>> list1 is list2
False
```